# Is there a way to set the file pointer back to the start of the current row?

Tags: c

I would like to check that the formatting of a file is correct, using fscanf, like this.

```
fscanf(fp, "%c%d %d %c%d", &ch, &a, &b, &ch2, &c);
```

Is there a way to get the file pointer back to the start of the current line after using this fscanf?
Is fseek a possible solution? if so, how?

Comment: find the position before the fscan and then use fseek -- is your question more than that?

Comment: @Hogan has a good suggestion.  You can use `ftell` to get file position before `fscanf` and then `fseek(fp, ???, SEEK_SET)` to go back to the beginning of the text file line.

Comment: does it include **`stdin`**?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to get the file pointer back to the start of the
>   current line after using this fscanf? Is fseek a possible solution? if
>   so, how?

Yes, there is! You can call the `ftell()` function before `fscanf` and then use `fseek` to restore to the saved location:

```c
long int savePos = ftell(fp);                       // save current location
fscanf(fp, "%c%d %d %c%d", &ch, &a, &b, &ch2, &c);  // do the test read
//.. do something to check your input...
fseek(fp, savePos, SEEK_SET);                       // restore position
```

See [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) for further information on the `ftell` function, but note:

> For text streams, the numerical value may not be meaningful but can
>   still be used to restore the position to the same position later using
>   fseek (if there are characters put back using ungetc still pending of
>   being read, the behavior is undefined).

Comment: Note that `fseek` may indicate an error if the underlying stream is not seekable, e.g. if it is a pipe, FIFO or socket.